# String format method. Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am learning how to use the string `format` method, and I've found something I don't understand. When I do:

```
>>> s = "My {comp[b]}"
>>> s.format(comp = {'a': 'laptop', 'b': 'desktop'})
'My desktop'
```

I get the expected results. But when I try to define the dictionary out of the method, and just used the name inside:

```
>>> comp = {'a': 'laptop', 'b': 'desktop'}
>>> s = "My {comp[b]}"
>>> s.format(comp)
```

I get `KeyError: 'comp'`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example you're not naming the parameter that you're passing to `format`. Your final line should be:

```
>>> s.format(comp=comp)
```

Answer (score 2):

`format` differentiates the use between positional and named arguments.

By using the name of the variable inside the format string, you are required to give a *named argument* with that specific name.
In the first you are because you are calling `"".format(<name>=<var>)` while in the second case your are just giving a positional argument (position 0) that is filled by the `comp` dictionary.

If you have read the documentation you have noticed that format can use positional arguments in this way: `"Hello {0}!".format(<arg0>)`.

In your second case, instead of giving the required name argument `comp` you are giving the position argument 0.